# File has no content after downloading xlsx file using http/net

Tags: go

I tried downloading an Excel file from a URL using `http/net` by calling the GET method. I don't know if this is releveant, but as for my case, I use dropbox to store the file on the cloud (it's open for public, not restricted, it can be accessed on incognito).

But when I open the file that's saved on the local, it has no content at all. It has just an empty sheet. The file is supposed to have filled with lots of data in cell.

What's happening here? Anyone knows how to solve it? There's no error at all when I print it.

```golang
func main() {
  filePath := "./file/filename.xlsx"
  url := "http://www.dropbox.com/somethingsomething.xlsx"

  out, err := os.Create(filePath)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  defer out.Close()

  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  defer resp.Body.Close()

  _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  return
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `resp.Body.Close()`? Also you can add extra check for example checking if the `statusCode == http.StatusOK` etc. It is possible that you got empty body when the `statusCode != http.StatusOK`

Comment: @mri1939 Status code is `200`. As for `resp.Body`, it's bunch of address. But for `resp.Body.Close()`, it's `<nil>`. So, what's happening here?

Comment: I think you are missing io reading here,
add io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

Answer (score 0):

Does the dropbox URL have dl=0 query param?
If so, try changing it to dl=1 to [force download](https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download) the file.

I tried the same with one of my files and it worked.
Thanks!

Comment: i just tried it but sadly it doesn't work either :/

Comment: You could try downloading the file once using curl in verbose mode. You will get some more information.

`curl -v -L -O {url}`